# Loss/ grief/ death tag

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I hope I am not imposing here.

I see you have a separation tag.

I wanted to suggest a grief tag (I created it, but can remove it).. or a death or loss tag.. which can all be placed under the one tag.

Sorry if this has already been suggested or such a tag exists. I have gone through the tags to familiarise myself, but am newish to  the site and am not  remembering them all, yet.

Am happy to write up some tag wikis if you like, let me know.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the [separation](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/separation) tag, we also have the [death](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) tag.

I'm wondering whether it's appropriate to throw *grief* and *loss* into [death](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death) as well. My analytical mind says it would be practical because they're all related anyway.

On the other hand, separating them gives more nuance and isn't quite as harsh-sounding and in that case I think that *grief* and *loss* should be synonyms rather than two separate tags.

Comment: Was the death tag there the whole time? I need glasses. Yes, I will leave it up to you guys to decide, am happy to write up tag wikis.. just didn't want to go off half cocked creating tags here cheers

Comment: Sorry I feel like an idiot, it's not the first time I've suggested a tag that exists.

Comment: I agree. "Separation" is a different topic from death (I just posted a question with that tag that was unrelated to death). I'm struggling to come up with a scenario where I think a grief/loss tag would be appropriate that isn't related to death, however. Perhaps we wait and see if such a question comes up in the future, and create the tag if and when it is needed?

Comment: @Beofett I think you're right, the separation tag covers the aspects of grief and loss that death doesn't. I didn't see the death tag. I can only think I looked with "de" rather than "dea" sorry about that

Comment: @Beofett and Torben would it be helpful if I wrote up some wiki tags?

Comment: @ThinksALot No problem... I can't say I've never missed a tag like that, myself :)  And yes, we always appreciate people writing tag wikis!  Thanks very much!

Comment: do you guys want me to remove the grief tag from my question so it will disappear???

Comment: You might find it easier to chat with us in the [chat] room? These comments quickly take up more space than the answer... Yes the "death" tag has been around a while already. No you don't need to remove the "grief" tag, it doesn't harm and we can always fix things later if it becomes relevant. You're welcome to go to [the tags page](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/tags) and write descriptions on anything that looks like it could need it.

Comment: *grief* and *loss* can both happen in a number of situations beyond just *death* or *separation*. I think it's perfectly fine to have those as additional tags available.